# html-webpack-plugin and webpack 2: no starting slash '/'

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin

I have a working webpack 1 project that I want to migrate to **webpack 2**.

It is almost working, my main remaining problem is with **html-webpack-plugin**:

when I use it in webpack 2, the generated script tag is of the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

instead of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Note: with the same plugin options, it works as expected in Webpack 1.

Here are the relevant parts of webpack conf:

```
  entry: [
    paths.appIndexJs,
    publicPath,
  ],
  output: {
    pathinfo: true,
    path: paths.appBuild,
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
  },

  // (...)

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting `output.publicPath` explicitly:

```
output : {
  filename   : 'static/js/bundle.js',
  path       : paths.appBuild,
  publicPath : '/'
}
```