# How to make Favicons Webpack Plugin not add an initial slash to assets directory

Tags: webpack, favicon

I am using Favicons Webpack Plugin to have the favicons in my site.

I have tried several ways but I cannot get the slash removed of the href directory.

I need href="assets/favicon-16x16.png" instead of href="/assets/favicon-16x16.png"

I tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43191900/3808307 and it still adds the slash

I also tried

```
plugins: [
  new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({   
    logo: '/path/to/logo.png',
    publicPath: '/',

})]
```

and

```
plugins: [
  new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({   
    logo: '/path/to/logo.png',
    publicPath: '',

})]
```

and outputPath: '' instead of publicPath: ''

and I cannot get rid of the slash.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem

```
plugins: [
  new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({   
    logo: '/path/to/logo.png',
    publicPath: '.',
})]
```