# nginx loading CSS/JS incorrectly when navigating to routes with more than one slash

Tags: nginx, static-site

I'm having an issue with nginx serving my static website files (CSS and JS) when you navigate to any route with more than one slash. For example, **example.com/test** works, but **example.com/test/test** will try and load the css/js from **example.com/test/{*.css|*.js}** instead of the root directory.

For context, I am using React and ReactRouter on this website.

*nginx config*

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html;

    rewrite ^.*$ /index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you specify the name of the CSS/JS file. You need to put a `/` in front.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191569/html-webpack-plugin-and-webpack-2-no-starting-slash

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was `html-webpack-plugin` not putting a **/** in front of the assets because `publicPath` was not set in the output.

See answer here: [html-webpack-plugin and webpack 2: no starting slash '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43191569/html-webpack-plugin-and-webpack-2-no-starting-slash)